# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2 "No such file or directory") CentOS

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am unable to start mysql after a lot of attempt. We are using MariaDB.

I am getting "**ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!**" When i am trying to restart.

Following is the output after entering **mysqld** command

> 160918  4:15:32 [Warning] Can't create test file
>   /var/lib/mysql/my-domain.lower-test
>
> 160918  4:15:32 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool
>   pages
>
> 160918  4:15:32 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
>
> 160918  4:15:32 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic 
>   builtins
>
> 160918  4:15:32 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
>
> 160918  4:15:32 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
>
> 160918  4:15:32 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
>
> 160918  4:15:32 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
>
> 160918  4:15:32 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
>
> 160918  4:15:32 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
>
> 160918  4:15:32 [ERROR] InnoDB: ./ibdata1 can't be opened in
>   read-write mode
>
> 160918  4:15:32 [ERROR] InnoDB: The system tablespace must be
>   writable!
>
> 160918  4:15:32 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
>
> 160918  4:15:32 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE
>   ENGINE failed.
>
> 160918  4:15:32 [ERROR] mysqld: File '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control'
>   not found (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
>
> 160918  4:15:32 [ERROR] mysqld: Got error 'Can't open file' when
>   trying to use aria control file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control'
>
> 160918  4:15:32 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
>
> 160918  4:15:32 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE
>   failed.
>
> 160918  4:15:32 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
>
> 160918  4:15:32 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run
>   mysql_upgrade to create it.
>
> 160918  4:15:32 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
>
> 160918  4:15:32 [ERROR] Aborting
>
> 160918  4:15:32 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete

What could be possible going wrong ?

Comment: What command do you use to restart MariaDB?

Comment: service mysql restart

Comment: Do you do that as root user ?

Comment: I tried with both root and non-root user

Comment: Sounds like some directories and/or files moved and/or changed ownership.  The problem is more than just the PID.